# Border-left for table cell not coming through in Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I am trying to give a left border to a table cell. It works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox and IE the border isn't displayed.

I saw in the documentation that left and right borders aren't widely supported but maybe there is a workaround or am I doing something wrong in the code.

The strange thing is that I have rounded borders in my table which have both left-borders and bottom borders and they are shown fine on each browser.

Here's the relevant code:

```
<tr class="Panel_Middle_Row">
    <td class="Panel_Middle_Left_Cell" width="20"></td>
    <td class="Panel_Middle_Middle_Cell">blablabla</td>
    <td class="Panel_Middle_Right_Cell"></td>
</tr>
```

And the according css:

```
.Panel_Middle_Left_Cell {
  width: 20px;
  border-left-style:solid;
  border-left-color:#CCC;
  border-left-width:2px;
}
.Panel_Middle_Right_Cell {
  width: 20px;
  border-right-style:solid;
  border-right-color:#CCC;
  border-right-width:2px;*/
}
```

You can find an example [here](http://cryo.dixys.com/Code/Webshop/WS_Shop.asp?CID=157&SCID=0&AID=1&LC=NL).

Comment: Put it on the row?? and do a shorthand like border-left:2px solid #ccc;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `td` are empty, ence they are not displayed. Add a `&nbsp;`.

Or add this to your table class : `empty-cells: show;`

Comment: adding "empty-cells:show;" works for FF indeed, thanks! but it makes no difference in IE

Comment: Did you try the &nbsp;? empty-cells only work with IE8+ when not in quirk mode (your webpage falls into quirkmode. You should add a doctype do your page unless you want to _code for IE6_.)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>    
td.Panel_Middle_Left_Cell {
  width: 20px;
  border-left-style:solid;
  border-left-color:#CCC;
  border-left-width:2px;
}

td.Panel_Middle_Right_Cell {
  width: 20px;
  border-right-style:solid;
  border-right-color:#CCC;
  border-right-width:2px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr class="Panel_Middle_Row">
    <td class="Panel_Middle_Left_Cell">jcjgcjgc</td>
    <td class="Panel_Middle_Middle_Cell">blablabla</td>
    <td class="Panel_Middle_Right_Cell"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```